# In a json schema, what is the correct way to describe a default, example, or enum value for a binary schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, openapi

In a schema in the 3 below contexts, what is the correct way to describe a default, example, or enum value for a binary schema?

```
type: string
format: binary
```

In openapi contexts, the above schema can be used as payload definition when sending multipart/form-data or application/octet-stream content media types.

Does the answer differ if one is using openapi(3.0.2 vs 3.1.0) vs json schema?
I have read the below specs but they lack examples for these use cases.

### openapi 3.1.0

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.1.0.md#considerations-for-file-uploads

Is format: binary no longer valid?
I read
`In contrast with the 3.0 specification, the format keyword has no effect on the content-encoding of the schema. JSON Schema offers a contentEncoding keyword, which may be used to specify the Content-Encoding for the schema.`
So it sounds like `contentEncoding: binary` should be used in 3.1.0 in place of `format: binary`
Does contentEncoding only apply to type: string schemas?

#### openapi 3.0.2

- https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.2.md#considerations-for-file-uploads
- https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.2.md#data-types

#### json schema 2020-12!

- https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/non_json_data.html

Comment: I think this depends on how you intend to store the OpenAPI document, and how you intend to use it (as in, with what tooling or platform, if any). I've shared this question in the right places so hopefully we can get you a good solid answer here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`format: binary` had limitations when you needed to specify both the media type and the encoding.  Specifically, this example from OAS 3.0.2:

```
requestBody:
  content:
    multipart/form-data:
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          profileImage:
            # default is application/octet-stream, need to declare an image type only!
            type: string
            format: binary
```

Note how it says that you "need to declare an image type only" because `format: binary` just indicates `application/octet-stream` (the universal media type that encompasses everything).

In OAS 3.1, the corresponding example is follows, sadly with an error- the comment about application-level encoded resources being `text/plain` is incorrect.  I seem to have missed that when I put this example in, my apologies- it is correct elsewhere in the spec:

```
requestBody:
  content:
    multipart/form-data:
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          profileImage:
            # Content-Type for application-level encoded resource is `text/plain`
            type: string
            contentMediaType: image/png
            contentEncoding: base64
```

These examples are slightly different as the OAS 3.1 shows a base64 encoding, which would have been `format: byte`.  The exact OAS 3.1 analogue would be:

```
requestBody:
  content:
    multipart/form-data:
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          profileImage:
            contentMediaType: image/png
```

without a `type` (because binary data, while valid in a multipart form submission which is what this is from, is not part of the JSON type system).

It is slightly confusing because the Encoding Object overlaps the JSON Schema keyword functionality a bit, which is the result of OAS and JSON Schema independently trying to solve the same problem.  OAS 3.1 specifies that if the Encoding Object is used, then JSON Schema's `contentMediaType` SHALL be ignored.  But you might still see both if the JSON Schema is intended for use both inside of and outside of OpenAPI.

---

JSON Schema's `examples`, `enum`, and `const` keywords take literal values.  As base64-encoded binaries are simply strings, they can be used with these keywords in the normal way.

However, *unencoded* binary cannot be embedded in JSON or YAML as a literal value.  The JSON Schema keywords were primarily designed for the JSON data model.

However, OpenAPI's [Example Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.1.0.md#exampleObject) (which is outside of the schema object) allows for an external reference to other media types.  There are not currently any such external reference keywords for JSON Schema, but the could be added as an extension vocabulary, meaning it is not necessary to wait for a new draft of JSON Schema or a new version of the OpenAPI Specification to do this.

`examples` and `default` are annotation keywords, and the default extension keyword behavior is to be an annotation, so there's not much you'd need to do to add them.  `const` and `enum` would be a bit more challenging as JSON Schema does not expect to load other media types for validation.  But `enum` has never supported unencoded binary data in OAS, nor did `example` or `default` in the OAS 3.0 Schema Object, so these are not new restrictions.

Comment: Is there no valid way to describe default / example / enum values for these use cases?

Comment: This no type defaulting to binary is unexpected and concerning. Aren't we storing a schema inside profileImage? In other schema contexts, no type means accept any possible type.

Comment: @spacether OpenAPI is written in YAML or JSON, and those media types do not support raw binary data.  I don't see how you could possibly specify a default or enum for such a thing.  You could do so with a base64-encoded string, just like any other string.

Comment: @spacether the issue with `type` and binary data is that binary data is not valid against any JSON Schema data model type.  So including the `type` keyword doesn't really work.  But it also doesn't matter because you should be taking your validation cue here from the media type (`image/png` plus the lack of any string-encoding data).  If you really want to exclude JSON data, I suppose you could do `{not: {type: [string, number, boolean, "null"]}}` but even if the schema passes, an implementation should never accept JSON where a PNG is specified.

Comment: So there's no way to set default/example/enum values for this use case. Can you update your answer to include that? Then I can accept it.

Comment: Done.  Please note that these are not new restrictions.  Except for the Example Object, which has always been outside of the Schema Object, it has never been possible to use these with raw unencoded binary.  Only string-encoded binary (which still works fine).